# git-p4 clone: after cloning, how to verify recursive file equivalence vs project in p4?

Tags: perforce, git, git-p4

I've migrated a project in perforce to git with complete checkin/commit history.

```
git p4 clone //path/to/project@all
```

How can I verify that the newly cloned git repo has recursive file equivalence to the originating data in p4?

Comment: you need to do some scripting and use diff.

Answer (score 0):

Each git commit will have a 1-1 correspondence with a perforce changelist.
And each commit message should list the equivalent changelist.

Therefore some scripting should allow you to checkout each git commit, and in another directory, checkout the Perforce tree at the appropriate changelist.
Then a recursive diff (ignoring the .git directory) should confirm they are the same.
Then iterate for all commits.